# How do i use webpack correctly?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, maven, webpack

I've just started a new Maven project. For my project i want to use the FullCalender from Fullcalendar.io. In order to use that i installed Node.js and cofigured webpack so i can import the Fullcalendar in my javascript file.

But here is my problem. Every time i write new code in my entry point file and i want to test it, i have to run 'npm run build' followed by maven clean and maven install in order for the changes to go through.
this makes testing obviously really time consuming. i think i'm using webpack wrong but i really don't know what. should i not write code in my entry point?

### entry point file

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/list/main.css';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin ],
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        }
    });
    fillCalendar(calendar);
    calendar.render();
});

function fillCalendar(calendar){
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/taken', {method : 'GET'}).then (function(response){
        return (response.text())
    })
        .then(function(data){
            var taken = JSON.parse(data);

            for(const taak of taken)
            {
                console.log(taak);
                addTaak(calendar, taak);
            }
        })
}

function addTaak(calendar, taak) {
    console.log(taak.naam);
    var taakObj = [
        {
            title: taak.naam,
            start: taak.datum,
            allDay: false
        }
    ];
    calendar.addEvent(taakObj)
}
```

Comment: are you trying to use webpack to run command-line codes for you??? Webpack is used to bundle and minify files such as css and js. If you're looking for something that will run cli for you, you might want too take a look at "make"

Comment: i'm using webpack so i can import all the fullcalendar script in my entry point file. but whenever something in that file changes, i have to run npm run build and maven clean install to view te effects in my browser. i'll edit my post with a picture of my entry point file.

Comment: To solve the portion of not needing to do npm run build, you might want to look at the "package.json" file, and you will see there the command it executes to the command line if you type npm run build....

Im pretty sure webpack has called a "watch mode" which will create a new distributable whenever the file changes... I am not sure about maven clean install though... Alternatively, you could add more code in the package.json so that it also runs maven clean install... but then again, I am not sure about maven

Comment: thank you, this already helped alot! i no longer have to run npm run build and i also dont have to run maven install. only thing left is maven clean but i think i can figure that out!

Comment: yey, thats good. I'll just put my comment as the answer so we could close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the portion of not needing to do npm run build, you might want to look at the "package.json" file, and you will see there the command it executes to the command line if you type npm run build.... Im pretty sure webpack has called a "watch mode" which will create a new distributable whenever the file changes... I am not sure about maven clean install though... Alternatively, you could add more code in the package.json so that it also runs maven clean install... but then again, I am not sure about maven